# how to add a button as html to a div and add click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the following code the button "alt2" shows up but does not alert "hi"

Is this the proper way to add a button?

```
<body>
<div id="test"></div><br>
<button id="add">add</button><br>
<button id='alt'>alt1</button>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function(){
    $("#add").click(function(){
        $("#test").html("<button id='alt2'>alt2</button>");     
    });
    $("#alt").click(function(){
        alert("hi");

    }); 

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`on("click")...` for the second alt2 is missing. also i would suggest you use `on("click")...` instead of `.("click")` . `.("click")` this one may miss to fire the second time

```html
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div><br>
<button id="add">add</button><br>
<button id='alt'>alt1</button>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function(){
 
 $(document).on("click", "#add", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    
        $("#test").html("<button id='alt2'>alt2</button>");     
    });
 
 
 $(document).on("click", "#alt", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    
        alert("hi 1");

    });  
 
 $(document).on("click", "#alt2", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    
        alert("hi 2");

    }); 

});

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: just a thought `submit` what? from `Also added the e.preventDefault(); to prevent the button from doing something else such as submitting`

Comment: @guradio using it or not using it in this context will have no harm. Just acting safe. But let me remove that **something else**

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("#add").click(function() {
  $("#test").html("<button id='alt2'>alt2</button>");
});
$("#alt").click(function() {
  alert("hi");

});

$(document).on('click',"#alt2",function() { // use .on()
  alert("hi 2");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
<br>
<button id="add">add</button>
<br>
<button id='alt'>alt1</button>
```

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for dynamically added elements.

> Description: Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.